# HttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream().Length throws exception even result is 200 OK status

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am trying to connect the web url from ASP.Net application to java web application using HttpWebRequest object and getting the status 200 OK. But when i try reading the response content using GetResponseStream() i am getting an error **'responseStream.Length' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'**

Here is the code

```
string uri="https://myapp.com/mainservlet/";

System.Net.HttpWebRequest hwrequest = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(uri);
            hwrequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
            hwrequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            hwrequest.UserAgent = "http_requester/0.1";
            hwrequest.Timeout = 60000;
            hwrequest.Method = "POST";
            if (hwrequest.Method == "POST")
            {
                hwrequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
                // Use UTF8Encoding instead of ASCIIEncoding for XML requests:
                System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
                byte[] postByteArray = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
                hwrequest.ContentLength = postByteArray.Length;
                 System.IO.Stream  poststream = hwrequest.GetRequestStream();
                poststream.Write(postByteArray, 0, postByteArray.Length);
                poststream.Close();
            }

            //Get the Response now.
            hwresponse = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)hwrequest.GetResponse();

         //  System.Xml.Linq.XDocument doc;
            //hwresponse.Method = "GET";
            string str = hwresponse.CharacterSet;
            string str1 = hwresponse.ContentEncoding;
            if (hwresponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {

                System.IO.Stream responseStream = hwresponse.GetResponseStream();
               // Here i am getting that exception
```

**Note:** When i try paste the same url in browser it says

*Error 404--Not Found 
From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:
10.4.5 404 Not Found
The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. No indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or permanent.
If the server does not wish to make this information available to the client, the status code 403 (Forbidden) can be used instead. The 410 (Gone) status code SHOULD be used if the server knows, through some internally configurable mechanism, that an old resource is permanently unavailable and has no forwarding address.*

Also it entered in 200 OK status and shows exception. Could some one help me how to resolve/ suggession?

Comment: Have you inspected the message and response with Fiddler? I'd be a bit suspicious of the 200 status if you cannot get a response stream.
.Net <-> Java can be lots of fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you checking if it is a post?

Try reading the stream like this instead. Then you can also set how much data of the webpage that you actually want.

```
Dim ResponseStream As Stream = Response.GetResponseStream()
            Try
                Dim reader As New StreamReader(Stream.Null)
                Try
                    reader = New StreamReader(ResponseStream, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(CharSet), True, 256)
                Catch ex As Exception

                    '
                    ' Redo the stream
                    '
                    If InStr(ex.Message, "not a supported encoding name.") > 0 Then
                        Try
                            reader = New StreamReader(ResponseStream, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"), True, 256)
                        Catch ex1 As Exception

                        End Try
                    End If
                End Try
                '
                'Dim string to build index.
                '
                Dim IndexBuildString As New StringBuilder()
                Try
                    Dim read(256) As [Char]
                    '
                    ' Reads 256 characters at a time.    
                    '
                    Dim ByteCount As Integer = reader.Read(read, 0, 256)
                    '
                    ' Read in while, exit it if exceeds ~ 390 kb
                    '
                    While ByteCount > 0
                        '
                        'Check if limit of kilobytes are over the limit.
                        '
                        If System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(IndexBuildString.ToString()) > 153600 Then
                            Exit While
                        End If
                        '
                        'Dumps the 256 characters to a string and displays the string to the console.
                        '
                        Dim str As New [String](read, 0, ByteCount)
                        ByteCount = reader.Read(read, 0, 256)
                        '
                        'Append to the StringBuilder
                        '
                        IndexBuildString.Append(str)
                    End While
                    '
                    'Assign the Stringbuilder and then clear it
                    ' 
                    IndexString = CleanIndexString(IndexBuildString.ToString())
                Catch ex As Exception

                Finally

                    Try
                        IndexBuildString.Clear()
                        reader.Close()
                        reader.Dispose()
                    Catch ex As Exception

                    End Try
                End Try
            Catch ex As Exception

            Finally
                ResponseStream.Dispose()
            End Try
```

You must add your own error handling....

Answer (score 1):

Use this to get the response have been using it for 4 years now always works.

```
 HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                responseData = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            response.Close();
```